# Extract instance of the bean that is getting the injected field from an InjectionPoint

Tags: cdi

In an InjectionPoint injectionPoint, we can obtain the class of the bean that is getting the injected field just by:

```
Bean<?> bean = injectionPoint.getBean();
String beanClass = bean.getBeanClass();
```

Is there a way to extract the instance of the bean that is getting the injected field?